# JasperReports: dynamic I18n

Tags: java, jasper-reports

For example I have such strings in ResourceBundle:

```
some.string.1=String 1
some.string.2=String 2
some.string.3=String 3
```

In JasperReports I have to print these strings based on some other parameter $P{t}.
I can do it this way - put such expression into field:

```
($P{t} == 1 ? $R{some.string.1} : ($P{t} == 2 ? $R{some.string.2} : $R{some.string.3}))
```

Is there any way to implement it that way:

```
$R{some.string.$P{t}}
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
str("some.string." + $P{t})
```

I have used similar things... though I don't remember using exactly this. It ought to work for what you're describing.

Comment: And how it will solve my problem? It will print out the variable's value. And I need to show the string from resource file in the current locale.

Comment: er... allow me to amend my useless answer. I meant "str" rather than "msg". The built-in str() method is the equivalent of the $R{} syntax. But it's dynamic, so you should be able to get what you need. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a java method to do it and embed the call directly in your jasper report.